# How can I have a column inside my flexible without it pushing out of the flexible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flexible that has a stack with 3 children. Each child is aligned differently. One is aligned left the other right and on in the middle. In the middle Align is the DigitalSpeedMeter() and that has a column with two texts. But the problem is that it's pushing out of the Flexible. How can I make it so that the DigitalSpeedMeter() scales to the height of the Flexible?

[image]

So the 7 mph is pushed up

**Parent Widget which holds the DigitalSpeedMeter()**

```
Flexible
(
  flex: 1,
  child: Stack
  (
    children: 
    [
      Align
      (
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: NavigatePopButton(),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: DigitalSpeedMeter(),
      ),
      Align
      (
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: SettingsButton(),
      ),
    ]
  ),
),
```

**DigitalSpeedMeter widget**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column
      (
        children: [
          Text(
            _speed.toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
          ),
          Text(
            globals.preferences.speedNotation.shortNotation,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body2,
          ),
        ]
      );
  }
```

Comment: in DigitalSpeedMeter widget, add Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min)

Answer (score 0):

try this widget tree

```dart
Row( 
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
 children: 
    [
      Align
      (
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: NavigatePopButton(),
      ),
      DigitalSpeedMeter(),
      Align
      (
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: SettingsButton(),
      ),
    ]
)
```

Comment: It get's a little better but it still doesn't center as you can see here https://prnt.sc/r932xe I added mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center and after that I tried to add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min which both gave similar results.

Comment: try MainAxisAlignment.center  with mainAxisSize MainAxisSize.max

Comment: Setting it to max gives the same result sadly

Comment: It produces the exact same result sadly

Comment: If I just a single text in the DigitalSpeedMeter() it aligns perfectly. I think it has something to do with the text. Is there a way to scale the text to its parents height?